# How can I restart the Timer after 10 seconds counting down?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to add a `Timer` displaying a countdown from 10.  When it reaches 0 it then needs to start again from 10.  This needs to be in a continuous loop.

This is what I have so far:

```
InitializeComponent();

        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Tick += myTimer_Tick;
        timer1.Start();

private void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = timeLeft.ToString();
        timeLeft -= 1;

        if (timeLeft < 0)
        {
            timer1.Tick += myTimer_Tick;
        }
    }
```

What's happening now is when it reaches 0 it continues in the minus, eg. -1 -2 -3 etc.
I need it to start again from 10.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you re-subscribing the event handler? It will make it call the handler multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply set the `timeLeft` back to ten

```
private void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = timeLeft.ToString();
    timeLeft -= 1;

    if (timeLeft < 0)
    {
        timeLeft = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :-) as simple as that :-)